# Как отправить oAuth данные клиента server и получить информацию из google analytics?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Нужно использовать  Google analytics api , возникла необходимость сохранить данные пользователя , и предоставить  доступ к данным другому пользователю,

Какие параметры  нужно сохранить для отправки запроса на авторизацию, client_id, API key, email ...  ?

Как  и куда отправлять эти данные для получения информации из google analytics ?

Можно ли отправить get запрос для авторизации через jquery ajax предварительно соединив параметры  ?

Буду благодарен если просто объясните что происходит и как нужно правильно делать.

Answer (score 1):

В Гугла есть готовая либа под PHP для роботы c их сервисами  - https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client . Там же есть документация и примеры. Вот [здесь](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth)  описана аутентификация.